# POST data to API without user login

Tags: api, rest, qr-code

Want to be able to post some simple data (e.g. multiple choice question) to an API server via a link that someone can access just by scanning a QR code, and without them having to login or have a user account.

I spoke with a developer about this and shivers went up their spine at the thought. How is this achievable? I get there are security implications...
Can I embed some sort of login on the QR code? Or can I send the data to some sort of proxy API and then pass the data securely from there?

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? Opening a link through a QRCode should open a common website, and yes, you can do all things with that website which you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Such an API can be implemented using standard HTTP like for any webpage where no user login is required.

To avoid spamming your API, you might want to retrict the number of calls according to the IP adress.